# Too much recurssion in google map

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markersArray = [];
        var infos = [];

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myOptions = {
              zoom: 9,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var encodedString;
        var stringArray = [];
        encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;
        stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

        var x;
        for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
        {
            var addressDetails = [];
            var marker;
            addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
            var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: lat,
                //Content is what will show up in the info window
                content: addressDetails[0]
            });

            markersArray.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
                closeInfos();
                var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
                //On click the map will load the info window
                info.open(map,this);
                infos[0]=info;
            });
           //Extends the boundaries of the map to include this new location
           bounds.extend(lat);
        }
        //Takes all the lat, longs in the bounds variable and autosizes the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        //Manages the info windows
        function closeInfos(){
       if(infos.length > 0){
          infos[0].set("marker",null);
          infos[0].close();
          infos.length = 0;
       }
        }

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='input'>

    <?php
   $encodedString = ""; 
    $x = 0;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table-name`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        if ( $x == 0 )
        {
             $separator = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $separator = "****";
        }
        $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
        "<p class='content'><b>Lat:</b> ".$row[1].
        "<br><b>Long:</b> ".$row[2].
        "<br><b>Name: </b>".$row[3].
        "<br><b>Address: </b>".$row[4].
        "</p>&&&".$row[1]."&&&".$row[2];
        $x = $x + 1;
    }        
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="<?php echo $encodedString; ?>" /> 
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

I have used above code for google map location from MySQL database.

Above code fetch lat, Lang from MySQL database and dynamically create google map.

When I run above code It gave me error like that:

There are two errors named `too much recursion` & `initMap is not function`.

Can anybody help me to sort out it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined initMap in your js file. That's why you are getting that error. You probably need to remove the callback part from the google map api script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

To

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" async defer></script>
```

Also check if the lat and lon contain valid numeric values in the following statement

```
var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
```